# Display dark 16-bit .tiff in Canvas

Tags: javascript, image-processing, canvas, tiff

I'm trying to display a 16-bit tiff image in a html5 canvas, I found this library [seikichi/tiff.js](https://github.com/seikichi/tiff.js/) and it works well but my images are dark, the pixel values are in the range [0- 300] then the image is quantized badly, the canvas displays a black image. I have tried other alternatives but I have the same problem. Is there any way to implement the quantization? Could suggest another solution or library?

PD: I get the image from a node.js server using ajax

Thanks!!

Comment: Please include more information regarding the result of the file load. Do you mean 16 bits total (RGB 565, or RGBa 5551) or is it a 16Bit per channel R16, G16 B16 ?  What values are in the range 0 -  300, there are 4 colour channels per pixel how does this range relate to those???

Comment: It is 16-bit gray scale only one channel, the values that are in [0-300] are the pixels value

Comment: The load of the file:<br/> var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
 <br/>xhr.responseType = 'arraybuffer';
 <br/>xhr.open('GET', "img/image.tif");
 <br/>xhr.onload = function (e) {
    <br/>var tiff = new Tiff({buffer: xhr.response});
     <br/>var bytes = new Uint8Array(xhr.response);
     <br/>var canvas = tiff.toCanvas();
     document.body.appendChild(canvas);
 };
 xhr.send();